# log4j-1.2-api bridge ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I try to migrate my application from log4j to log4j2. According to [official manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) I have `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.17.1`, `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1` and `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1` in my maven dependencies. I use `log4j.properties` file so I enabled compatibility mode (`-Dlog4j1.compatibility=true`). `RollingFileAppender` is configured in my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

I get following error:

```
2022-02-16 21:04:20,396 main ERROR Unable to create Appender org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender due to ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

According to [official manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html), `RollingFileAppender` is a supported component. I had `log4j:log4j:1.2.17` dependency before migration to log4j2 and it contains `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` class. Unfortunately none of the `log4j-1.2-api`,`log4j-api` and `log4j-core` libraries contain this class. I do not understand why `RollingFileAppender` is not present in log4j bridge if manual says that `RollingFileAppender`  is supported component. I have found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317504/log4j-2-migration-bridge-log4j-1-2-api-jar-missing-classes) but without a satisfactory answer. How to migrate `RollingFileAppender`?

**UPDATE**

Here is my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, A1, A2

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d%m%M %n

log4j.appender.A2.file=C:/projects/test/Log.log
#log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd.MM HH.mm.ss.SSS} %-5p %-20c{1}] : %m%n
#log4j.appender.A2.MaxFileSize=10000KB
#log4j.appender.A2.MaxBackupIndex=3
```

I added `-Dlog4j2.debug=true`. There are tons of logs. I chose interesting logs:

```
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2437c6dc.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Log4j Builder' found 18 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, A1, A2].
DEBUG StatusLogger Level token is [INFO].
DEBUG StatusLogger Logger root level set to INFO
DEBUG StatusLogger Parsing appender named "A1".
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 47 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
DEBUG StatusLogger Adding appender named [A1] to loggerConfig [].
DEBUG StatusLogger Parsing appender named "A2".
WARN StatusLogger Unable to create File Appender, no file name provided
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Appender org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender due to ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender named [A2] not found.
DEBUG StatusLogger Finished configuring.
```

Comment: How are you building your application? Are you shading all jars into one? In Log4j 1.x bridge `RollingFileAppender` is not a class, it's an `AppenderBuilder` plugin (see [javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/builders/appender/RollingFileAppenderBuilder.html)).

Comment: No, I am not shading all jars into one.

Comment: Run your application with `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` and check the `stderr` stream for errors. Can you update your question and add the whole configuration of the `RollingFileAppender`? Incorrect configuration values can also cause the problems you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason configuration fails is explained by the following message:

```
WARN StatusLogger Unable to create File Appender, no file name provided
```

This is caused by a compatibility problem between the Log4j 1.x bridge and the original Log4j 1.x: property names must start with a capital letter (cf. [LOG4J2-3316](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3316)). This will be solved in the next release.

Until then, you can use:

```
log4j.appender.A2.File=C:/projects/test/Log.log
```

(with a capital `F`).